# Using parent component's template in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to inherit parent's template using component's inheritance in Angular.

**Intro**

I have some basic component (let's call it `ParentComponent`) and several childs of this component (`Child1Component` and `Child2Component`). I want to put default behavior in the `ParentComponent` and then just setup/extend this behavior in children components. `ParentComponent` template already contains all the needed things, so I want children components to use this template by default.

---

**First variant of implementation** (does not work, `Error: No template specified for component Child1Component`):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    templateUrl: './app-parent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent {
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-child1'
})
export class Child1Component extends ParentComponent {
}


@Component({
    selector: 'app-child2'
})
export class Child2Component extends ParentComponent {
}
```

---

I found that I can set `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` of children to parent's template, but it will work only if `ViewEncapsulation` of children is set to `None`.

**Second variant** (it works, but I don't like it):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    templateUrl: './app-parent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent {
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-child1',
    templateUrl: '../parent/app-parent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../parent/app-parent.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class Child1Component extends ParentComponent {
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-child2',
    templateUrl: '../parent/app-parent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../parent/app-parent.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class Child2Component extends ParentComponent {
}
```

I don't like this solution cause of

1. No view encapsulation in child components;
2. Template and style urls copy-paste for every child component.

---

Can you please suggest me better solution for this task?

Comment: I'd suggest rethinking the approach slightly. You don't really want to inherit the template, if you want it to be the same for all children, just use template URL and reference the same file. If it is to be different, use an ng-template to switch out the portions that are to be different..... inheritance here is only useful for sharing behavior (if even that, there are other ways), once you try to start inheriting templates its probably e an indication that you need to separate your complements differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second approach is the only possible way, because there are rules for decorator inheritance, see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11606.

`@Component` decorator can not be partially inherited, it is all or nothing.

Comment: It's really disappointing. I'll dig a bit `@Component` decorator, maybe I can 
 inherit/override it to achieve the desired behavior. I'll mark your answer accepted in a few hours – just want to wait for other potential solutions and suggestions.

Comment: You could probably make it work in JIT mode, but not in AOT.